# MySQL InnoDB Transactions + Locking

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, innodb

MySQL Verion: v5.0.95

Basically I have clients trying to get data - each client should only get unique rows.

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT id where result='new';

UPDATE SET result='old' WHERE id=$id;

COMMIT;
```

`LOCK IN SHARED MODE` on the select statement still lets other clients read the data, which seems like a problem.

Basically I need the data selected once, updated, and not read again by another client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SELECT FOR UPDATE` will block another read, while `LOCK IN SHARED MODE` will allow the read, but won't allow update from another client